# getting parse error in plotting "Expected end of text, found '$'"

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I was trying to plot the two columns with artist name and loudness from a spotify data. but while trying to do the same I am getting error

ValueError:
Joey Bada$$
^
Expected end of text, found '$'  (at char 9), (line:1, col:10)
while inspecting I found there are data rows with the values like the "Joey Bada$$" in the data rows.
Can  some one please help me? whether the regex concept can be used in order to avoid this issues. used code is given below;

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))
plt.scatter(spotifydata['artist_name'],spotifydata['loudness'] )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib interprets everything between $ signs as [math text](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html). As far as I know this can't be switched off.

If you want to remove the $$ signs:

```
plt.scatter(spotifydata['artist_name'].str.replace('\$\$',''), spotifydata['loudness'])
```

if you want to keep the $$ signs:

```
plt.scatter(spotifydata['artist_name'].str.replace('\$\$','\\$\\$'), spotifydata['loudness'])
```